# Is it possible render something before the component will unmount?

Tags: reactjs

I created a custom Modal. In the component mount I put the className "visible" with a simple opacity: 1.

Since the Modal has a transition, I also want to put a className "gone" with opacity 0 in the unmount of the component.

Is it possibile wait the transition of the close before unmount it and do something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
   setClassname('visible');

   return () => {
      setClassname('gone');

      setTimeout(()=>{
         OK, NOW U CAN UNMOUNT!
      ), 200 // time of the transition}
   }
}, []);
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I think React Transition Group can help you. https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/

You should not remove class in unmount, just do this logic in parent component, using React Transition Group. You can find an example
of transition here https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition